# Create a login php where details are stored in xml

Tags: php, xml

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customers>
  <customer>
    <customerID>1747267206223730</customerID>
    <firstname>123</firstname>
    <lastname>123</lastname>
    <email>123@123.com</email>
    <phone>0444444444</phone>
    <password>123</password>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <customerID>1747267238619299</customerID>
    <firstname>123</firstname>
    <lastname>123</lastname>
    <email>1234@123.com</email>
    <phone>0482222222</phone>
    <password>123</password>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <customerID>1747267243491036</customerID>
    <firstname>123</firstname>
    <lastname>123</lastname>
    <email>12345@123.com</email>
    <phone>0482222222</phone>
    <password>123</password>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <customerID>1747267246407122</customerID>
    <firstname>123</firstname>
    <lastname>123</lastname>
    <email>1234556@123.com</email>
    <phone>0482222222</phone>
    <password>123</password>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <customerID>1747269825276695</customerID>
    <firstname>afdasc</firstname>
    <lastname>vadscas</lastname>
    <email>test@test.com</email>
    <phone>0485555555</phone>
    <password>321</password>
  </customer>
</customers>
```

Here is what I tried:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["email"]) && isset($_GET["cPassword"])){
    
    $loginEmail=$_GET["email"];
    $loginPwd=$_GET["cPassword"];

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load('../../data/customer.xml');
    $customers = $doc->getElementsByTagName('customers');

    foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    $email = $customer->getElementsByTagName('email')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $password = $customer->getElementsByTagName('password')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    
    if( $email == $loginEmail && $password == $loginPwd)
    {
        echo "found the result";
    }
    
}

}
?>
```

I know login details should not be stored in xml. This is a practice for using php and xml.
Right now I am only able to make the php search for the first matched email.

Is there any way I could improve the code for it to loop through all the nodes, and if the system finds the match email, then search within that child for the password?
Thank you.

Comment: Add `break;` after the line `echo "found the result";`

Comment: Agreed with @KenLee. when you found one stop the loop execution. otherwise in the next iteration, it will not find a match, and you are left with nothing printing even match is there

Comment: If you are looking to just optimize things, you could probably write an XPath query to search for the specific email and password instead of looping

Answer (score 0):

Never store the password, store a hash. PHP has an API for this. Then fetch the user by their identifier and verify the password.

Create a password hash:

```php
echo password_hash('123', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

You will notice that the hash changes each time you create a hash. It contains a random value. Here is `password_verify()` to verify a stored hash against a password input.

```php
$email = '123@123.com';
$password = '123';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(getXMLString());
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

/* fetch customer element node by email */
$userNode = $xpath->evaluate('//customer[email = "'.$email.'"]')->item(0);
$isValidUser = false;
if ($userNode) {
  $isValidUser = password_verify(
    $password,
    /* fetch password element contents as string */
    $xpath->evaluate('string(password)', $userNode)
  );
}

echo $isValidUser ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid';

function getXMLString() {
    return <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customers>
  <customer>
    <customerID>1747267206223730</customerID>
    <firstname>123</firstname>
    <lastname>123</lastname>
    <email>123@123.com</email>
    <phone>0444444444</phone>
    <password>$2y$10$yp9AojnV7T9966V3JKc3EOVozyJmmr6hbU.WGRoK9A4qPGicG.9hO</password>
  </customer>
</customers>
XML;
}
```

And yes, you should not be using XML for storage but a database. XML is for data exchange between different systems.